# Does array_rand use the Mersenne Twister algorithm?

Tags: php, random, mersenne-twister

In PHP, we have the choice of [mt_rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) and [rand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) where `mt_rand()` uses the Mersenne Twister algorithm and `rand()` uses the libc random generator.

I would like to choose a random item out of an array using [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php). However,  does `array_rand` use the Mersenne Twister algorithm?

It is quite simple to implement my own `array_rand` using `mt_rand`, but if array_rand uses the Mersenne Twister, then all the better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that [`array_rand`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L3958) uses [`php_rand()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/rand.c#L63) internally, which appears to be the <strike>good</strike> old non-mt version.

Answer (score 4):

[It does now](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/ab834f4), as of PHP 7.1; see [this RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/rng_fixes) and this [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45301) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

It was probably not the case since results from `array_rand()` used to be [not random at all](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45301). It's been fixed in latest releases (see [Vaxquis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47625739/13508) for the details).